# What exactly is the group law?

Tags: abstract-algebra

is it the operation symbol?  is it the equation that defines that symbol? (such as $a\star b=a+b+ab$) or what is it if it's none of the above

Comment: "Law" here has the sense of a rule.   In this context it means the rule that *defines* the group operation.  The same set of objects *might* be considered to have a variety of group operations defined, provided each definition satisfies the axioms for a group (associativity, identity, inverses).

Comment: The group law on a group $G$ is not the "symbol", but it is the [binary operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation) that the symbol is notation for.

Comment: Please *search* before asking, e.g. on the first page of "group law" matches is the [Wikipedia 'Group' page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)): which states "A group is a set, G, together with an operation • (called the group law of G)..."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because lacks research (searching)

Answer (score 4):

If $G$ denotes the set on which the group law is defined, then the group law is the map $f : G \times G \rightarrow G$ such that for every $x,y \in G$, $f(x,y) = x*y$.

Answer (score 1):

This might help. It could also make things worse. The example you give uses the real numbers, but transports the structure.

Given a  group, we can take any bijection $\varphi$ to (or from...) some slightly different base set, and create a  group.

Namely, the real numbers **not equal to zero** are a group under multiplication.

In the direction I thought of first, our first set will be $\mathbb R \setminus \{-1 \} ,$ while the second set is $\mathbb R \setminus \{0 \} .$ The second set is already a group. We pull back the group operation using, for any $x \neq -1,$
$$ \varphi(x) = x+1 \; , \; $$
$$  x \star y = \varphi^{-1} \left( \varphi(x) \cdot \varphi(y) \right) $$
I deliberately typed in a $\cdot$ to show where the original group operation happens, that being real multiplication.  We get
$$ x \star y = (x+1)(y+1) - 1 = xy + x + y    $$